# Show that $P(A_n\cap B_n)$ is of smaller order than $n^{-1/2}$.

Tags: probability

Let $A_n\subseteq A_n', B_n\subseteq B_n'$ and $A_n'$ and $B_n'$ independent events with $P(A_n')=P(B_n')$. Moreover, let $P(A_n)\sim 1/\sqrt{54\pi n}$. It is to show that $P(A_n\cap B_n)$ is of smaller order than $n^{-1/2}$.

Of course, it is
$$
P(A_n\cap B_n)\leq P(A_n'\cap B_n')=P(A_n' P(B_n')=(P(A_n'))^2.
$$

Now, it is said that the asymptotic formula
$$
\sqrt{n} P(A_n)\to\text{ a limit }
$$
implies
$$
P(A_n')\leq c/n^{1/2}
$$
for some constant $c$.

I do not see the last point. Why is $P(A_n')\leq c/n^{1/2}$ for some constant $c$?

Answer (score 0):

As written, the claim does not follow. It is consistent with the given conditions that $P(A_n)=\frac1{\sqrt{54\pi n}}$, $P(A_n')=P(B_n')=P(B_n)=1$

Comment: Does it make a difference that it is said that $P(A_n)\sim 1/\sqrt{54\pi n}$ and not $=$?

Comment: No. Note that $P(A_n)=...\implies P(A_n)\sim ...$. The problem is that nothing bounds $P(A_n')$ from above (except that it is $\le 1$)

Comment: By the way, does $n^{-1}$ be of smaller order than $n^{-1/2}$?! I think, yes, because $1/n\leq n^{-1/2}$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Hagen: The claim holds, by a completely different and elementary road: $P(A_n\cap B_n)\leqslant P(A_n)\in\Theta(1/\sqrt{n})$, QED. I suspect the rest are deadends invented by the OP.